# Installing VLC SUSE Linux enterprise Desktop 11 SP2

Tags: linux, vlc, suse

I am attempting to install VLC client and VLC-Mozilla Plugin on *SLED 11 SP2(32bit)*. I have followed the instructions on a number of websites and yet still have failed.

I have attempted packman repositories, and most recently this:

## Add the repositories

```
zypper ar -f http://download.videolan.org/pub/vlc/SuSE/11.2 vlc && zypper refresh vlc
zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/multimedia:/libs/SLE_11_SP3/ multimedia-libs && zypper refresh multimedia-libs
zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/multimedia:/xine/SLE_11 multimedia-xine && zypper refresh multimedia-xine
```

## Install VLC

```
zypper in vlc
```

however I get the dependency issue:

```
Problem: nothing provides libcdio.so.10 needed by vlc-nox-1.1.13-4.2.i586
```

I am stumped for ideas so any ideas you can provide will be extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

I used the commands that you provided us, except for the second line, and it worked for me Surfing on the WEB, I found this:

[How to Installing VLC on SLED 11 SP1](http://www.suse.in.th/how-tofaq-%28beginner-skill%29/how-to-installing-vlc-on-sled-11-sp1/)

Instead of using the second instruction, write this.-

```
zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/multimedia:/libs/SLE_11/ multimedia-libs && zypper refresh multimedia-libs
```

I'm using SLED 11 SP3. I hope that this can help you.